# Бот дискорд банит тех кого запрещено банить

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Бот дискорд банит тех кого нельзя банить, я задал переменную "a" в значение "user" а потом вывел его:

код:

```
@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, user: discord.User):
    a = user
    print (a)
    if a == "никнейм#0000":
        await ctx.send(f'пользователь в белом списке')
    else:     
        await ctx.guild.ban(user)
        await ctx.send(f'пользователь {user}/{user.mention} был забанен')
```

вывелся пользователь, которого упоминали (не id, а сам никнейм, что я посчитал странным), но когда я написал условие что если a == "никнейму" не банить, все равно пользователь отправлялся в бан...

Comment: попробуйте if a.name == "никнейм#0000":

Comment: @Jack_oS нет, это не сработало

Comment: Может быть никнейм в каком-то другом атрибуте лежит? Читали https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User ? Фишка же в том, что `a` имеет тип `user.Discord`, а сравнить пытаетесь со строкой. Это гарантированный вечный `False`

Comment: и как можно перевести user.Discord в строку?

Comment: Этого вовсе не нужно делать, достаньте из объекта никнейм, только и всего, ссылку я скинул:) В каком-то атрибуте он точно лежит!:) Надо лишь чуть подразобраться, что где лежит

Comment: Я изучаю discord.py не так давно и не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: Начните с изучения python, значит. Я не шучу и не издеваюсь...

Comment: или a.name, или a.display_name https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#user

Comment: @Jack_oS спасибо, заработало

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше используйте ID. Так куда проще написать код, но понять будет сложнее.

```
if a.id == {whitelisted_id}:
    return await ctx.send("User in whitelist!")
else:
    #do your expensive stuff here
```

Учтите, что ID - целое число, а не строка.